# Is this graph based on rationals familiar?

Tags: probability, graphing-functions, rational-numbers

Has anyone come across a graph like this?

[image]

The black circles represent rationals in $(0,1)$ and their heights are roughly proportional to the reciprocal of the square of their lowest terms denominator.  The red lines are drawn by eye on the pattern of the black dots.

This came from trying to create a probability distribution on the rationals where $$\Pr\left(X = \frac{a}{b}\right) = \frac{\zeta(k)}{\zeta(k-1) - \zeta(k) } \left(\frac{1}{b}\right)^k$$ where $0 \lt a \lt b$ with $a$ and $b$ coprime and where $k \gt 2$.

The red lines look somewhat like the left half of the Stern-Brocot Tree except that points with different denominators are at different heights.

Comment: This is a very nice looking graph.

Comment: I'd say that the red lines _are_ the left half of the Stern-Brocot tree. The heights used in a diagram that _represents_ the tree are not an intrinsic feature of the _tree_ itself.

Comment: It seems interesting and highly symmetric like a gaussian or laplace distribution. Meanwhile what is $\zeta$

Comment: I think you mean the heights are roughly proportional to the *reciprocal* of the square of the denominator. The function $f(p/q)=1/q$, $f(x)=0$ for $x$ irrational is the standard example of a function continuous at $x$ if and only if $x$ is irrational. You are (roughly) squaring that function.

Comment: @Seyhmus: $\zeta(k)$ is the [Riemann zeta function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_zeta_function)

Comment: @Gerry: Fair point - I will edit

Comment: There is somewhat similar graph here http://blogs.scientificamerican.com/critical-opalescence/2012/08/06/how-do-you-count-parallel-universes-you-cant-just-go-1-2-3/

Comment: "their heights are roughly proportional to the reciprocal of the square of their lowest terms denominator"  Substitute "exactly" for "roughly" and you've got the locations of the centers of the Ford circles.  See my answer below.

Comment: Nice graph. What value of $k$ did you use to make the graph? Also, how did you obtain the normalizing constant?

Comment: @apelt001 $k$ marginally over $2$ and since there is no marked vertical scale there is no need to normalise to draw the graph.  $\Pr\left(X = \frac{a}{b}\right) = \frac{\zeta(k)}{\zeta(k-1) - \zeta(k) } \left(\frac{1}{b}\right)^k$ indicates what it would be

Comment: @Henry yes it’s just interesting that the normalizing constant is what it is, and I’m not sure how that works, because the lebesgue integral of such a density function between $0$ and $1$ would evaluate to $0$.

Comment: @apelt001 It is not a density function but a probability mass function, which sums to $1$ over $q\in \mathbb Q \cap (0,1)$, for $k>2$

Comment: @Henry Oh I see, thanks for explaining my mistake. I got my own answer to the normalizing constant: $$\sum_{a,b:\ (a,b)=1 \\ 0<\frac{a}{b}< 1} = \sum_{b=2}^\infty\sum_{(a,b)=1} (\frac{1}{b})^k = \sum_{b=2}^\infty \frac{\varphi(b)}{b^k}=\frac{\zeta(k-1)}{\zeta(k)}-1.$$

Comment: @apelt001 dividing by $\frac{\zeta(k-1)}{\zeta(k)}-1$ is the same as multiplying by $\frac{\zeta(k)}{\zeta(k-1) - \zeta(k) }$

Comment: @Henry I know. I was just stating that that's the answer I wanted thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As Gerry mentions, this is (roughly) the square of [Thomae's function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thomae%27s_function), also known as the popcorn function, the raindrop function, the countable cloud function, the modified Dirichlet function, the ruler function, the Riemann function, or the Stars over Babylon...

Comment: Rahul Can you help [Connection of complex $e^z$ and real Dirichlet](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2867643/) please?

Comment: @BCLC No thanks, that doesn't look like a question I would like to answer.

Answer (score 3):

It is surprising that no one has mentioned [Ford circles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ford_circle).  The heights of the centers of Ford circles are exactly proportional to the reciprocals of the denominators.

Let us suppose that the content of the section on [total area of Ford circles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ford_circle#Total_area_of_Ford_circles) is correct.  Then if a point is randomly chosen in the interior of one of the Ford circles corresponding to a rational number in the interval $[0,1]$, the probability of its being in any region proportional to the region's area, then the probability that it is in the circle corresponding to a particular rational number with denominator $k$ is
$$
\frac{\zeta(4)}{\zeta(3)} \left(\frac 1 k\right)^4.
$$