# Constructing a Measure on the Rational Numbers

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I was wondering if there is any known examples of measures on the set of rational numbers besides Lebesgue measure.  In particular, an example of a probability measure on $\mathbb{Q}$ would be nice to see.

Here is a somewhat naive attempt:  Let $X = \mathbb{Q}, \Sigma = 2^X $, the sigma algebra which is the set of all subsets of $\mathbb{Q}$.  Now for $E \subset \Sigma$ define $m(E) = \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{|E \cap \{ q_1, q_2, ..., q_n \}|}{n}$ where $(q_j)_{j=1}^\infty$ is an enumeration of the rationals and $|A|$ denotes the cardinality of a finite set $A$.  Is this a probability measure?

Comment: How do you define the limit if it doesn't exist?

Comment: can you give me an example of a set for which it does not exist?

Comment: For any fixed set $E \in \mathcal{P(\mathbb{Q})}$ the sequence $a_n = \frac{|E \cap \{q_1, ..., q_n \}|}{n}$ is a bounded and monotonic sequence, so the limit exists.

Comment: It is not monotonic. For example, consider the following set of indexes $$ \cup_{ n \geq 1} \{2^{2n}, 2^{2n}+1,..., 2^{2n+1}-1 \}$$ For this set the limit doesn't exist. Look at your fraction when the denominator is an odd vs. an even power of 2.

Comment: To make things clearer, your sequence for which you wrote the limit is increasing from $n$ to $n+1$ if $q_{n+1} \in E$ and decreasing if $q_{n+1} \notin E$. So by having long strings of numbers in $E$ followed by long strings of numbers not in $E$, you can make the sequence oscilating, and this is exactly what I did in the above example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, your suggestion is not a probability measure as it is not additive over countable unions of disjoint sets.

If $t$ is a natural number then $m(\{q_t\})= \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac1n=0$ and so $\sum_t m(\{q_t\})=0$. But $m( \mathbb{Q})= \lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{n}{n}=1$.

You need a discrete measure.

For example $\mathbb{Q} \cap (0,1)$ you could use $m \left( \left\{ \frac{a}{b} \right\}\right) =\frac{\zeta(k)}{\zeta(k-1) - \zeta(k) } \left(\frac{1}{b}\right)^k$ for some $k\gt2$ and $a$ and $b$ coprime; this can be extended to all rationals.

Comment: Is $\zeta$ the riemann zeta function?  How do you prove that your $m$ is a measure.  A reference would be nice.

Comment: It gives a positive value to each rational in $(0,1)$ and $\sum  \left(\frac{1}{b}\right)^k = \frac{\zeta(k-1) - \zeta(k) }{\zeta(k)}$ where $\zeta$ is the Riemann zeta function, so the total probability is $1$.  See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/189813/is-this-graph-based-on-rationals-familiar for a picture.

Comment: See [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function#Generating_functions) saying $\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\varphi(n)}{n^s}=\frac{\zeta(s-1)}{\zeta(s)}$, pointing at Hardy & Wright (1979), An Introduction to the Theory of Numbers, theorem 288.

Answer (score 4):

A simple example of such a measure is the following, but this is a boring example.

Let $\{ q_n \}_{n=1}^ \infty$ be an enumeration of the rationals.

Define
$$m=\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{2^k} \delta_{q_k} \,.$$
This measure can be defined alternatelly
$$m(E) = \sum_{ q_n \in E} \frac{1}{2^n}$$

Comment: Could you please show why this measure you propose is a probability measure on $\mathbb{Q}$? In other words, why does it satisfy countable additivity and why does it yield results between [0,1], 0 for the empty space and 1 for the entire space? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Note that $m({q}) = 0$ for every $q \in \mathbb{Q}$, whereas $m(\mathbb{Q}) = 1$, so $m$ cannot be $\sigma$-additive. This argument shows that there are no probability measures on a denumerable set that assign the same measure to every singleton.

Moreover, the limit in your definition does not always exist.

There are, however, interesting examples of **finitely** additive measures (or probability charges). The example you mention if in fact to being a probability charge, but one must be careful enough to consider the cases where the limit does not exist [see this article](http://www.stat.cmu.edu/tr/tr814/oldtr814.pdf).

Comment: A related article on finitely additive measures, from much earlier: http://matwbn.icm.edu.pl/ksiazki/fm/fm65/fm6513.pdf