# Singular Measure with Dense Support

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Is there a measure $\mu$ with support $S \subseteq [0,1]$ such that it satisfies:

(i) $S$ has Lebesgue measure zero but is dense on $[0,1]$ with respect to the standard metric;

(ii) $\mu(S)<\infty$; and

(iii) **$\forall \epsilon>0$**, $\forall a,b \in [0,1]$ such that $b-a\geq \epsilon >0$, $\mu((a,b])\geq k(\epsilon)>0$.

The Cantor distribution fails (i).
It is unclear to me that taking the route of the answers [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1000359/constructing-a-measure-on-the-rational-numbers) ensures (iii).

The main reason I am asking this is that this possibility is mentioned in [Diaconis and Freedman, 1990, p. 1317](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.aos/1176347751), but I'm struggling to construct such a measure.

Edit: (iii) should hold $\forall \epsilon>0$. Apologies for the imprecision.

Comment: In fact the _support_ is closed by definition, so if it's dense then it's $[0,1]$. You meant to say "... a measure $\mu$ concentrated on $S$".

Comment: $S=\mathbb{Q}\cap[0,1]$ is dense in $[0,1]$ but $S \ne [0,1]$.

Comment: And that set $S$ is also _not closed_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

let $S$ be the set of dyadic rational numbers in $[0,1]$ (i.e. all rational numbers of the form $a/2^k$, with $0\leq a\leq 2^k$ and $a$ odd), and let $\mu(\{a/2^k\})=1/2^{2k}$. Property (i) is immediate. Further,$\mu$ is finite because there are at most $2^k$ dyadic rationals in $[0,1]$ with denominator $2^k$, so the measure of all such rationals is at most $2^k/2^{2k}=1/2^k$, and summing over all possible $k$ gives (ii).

to see $(iii)$, suppose $b-a>\epsilon>0$. Choose $k(\epsilon)$ so that $2^{-k(\epsilon)}<\epsilon$. The crucial observation is that there must exist a dyadic rational number in $(a,b)$ with denominator $2^{k(\epsilon)}$ or less. Then $(iii)$ follows immediately from this observation, since $\mu([a,b])$ would then be at least $2^{-2*k(\epsilon)}$.

To see why the observation is true, observe that  the set of all such dyadic rationals is equal to $0, 1/2^{k(
\epsilon)}, 2/2^{k(\epsilon)}, \dots, 1$, i.e. they are evenly spaced with the gap between successive terms being $1/2^{k(\epsilon)}$. Since the distance between $a$ and $b$ is larger than this gap, the observation follows.

Comment: Curiously, (almost) exactly the same as my example (I was typing while yours appeared...)

Comment: Edit: my mistake. I misread.

Answer (score 2):

Say $S_n=\{1/n,2/n,\dots,(n-1)/n,1\}$, and let $\mu_n$ be the probability measure uniformly distributed on $S_n$. It's easy to verify that $$\mu=\sum2^{-n}\mu_n$$works.

Comment: Edit: My mistake. Terribly sorry.

Comment: @user_newbie10 Did you read the other answer? He gives a detailed explanation of why (iii) holds for every $\epsilon>0$.